# How do I skip a DataGridViewRow?

Tags: vb.net

I am looping through rows in a DataGridView as follows:

```
For Each orow As DataGridViewRow In GV_NS.Rows
    If orow.Cells(0).Value.Length = 0 Then
        //Skip this row and go to next row
    Else
        //do this
    End If
Next
```

I would like to be able to skip to the next row if the first column is null.  I tried just using `Next` in `If orow.Cells(0).Value.Length = 0`, but it was throwing the syntax error `If must end with matching End If`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just reverse your test.

```
For Each orow As DataGridViewRow In GV_NS.Rows
    If orow.Cells(0).Value.Length <> 0 Then
        //do this
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To skip to the next iteration of a `For`, `Do`, or `While` loop, use `Continue` like so:

```
For Each orow As DataGridViewRow In GV_NS.Rows
    If orow.Cells(0).Value.Length = 0 Then
        //Skip this row and go to next row
        Continue For
    Else
        //do this
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You could also drop the else and write the code after the `End If`, to avoid deep nesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'Filter rows with LINQ
    Dim Query = From row In GV_NS.Rows
        Where CType(row, DataGridViewRow).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Length > 0
        Select row
    For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In CType(Query.ToArray, DataGridViewRow())
        'Do something
    Next
```